# String[] array length isnt equal to the actual number of elements inside it

Tags: java, arrays, spring, hibernate, tostring

I have a big project im working on, there is a piece of code where i get 2 arrays of String from an http post request on my server using spring and hibernate (json format), when i print the arrays size i get 1 in return, but at the same time i have (as i should/want/expect) 2 elements inside it so when i iterate over the array with the expected length i get an "array out of bound exception" and that's really weird imo.

p.s. - this problem repeats itself in other places as well, maybe its has something to do with hibernate/spring?.

output:

```
deviceAaddr - size = 1, [0022C01504D3,0022C015050F]
devicePass - size = 1, [HOMI26,HOMI26]
```

json:

```
{"deviceAddr":["0022C01504D3,0022C015050F"],"devicePass":["HOMI26,HOMI26"],"deviceCount":2,"version":"MU18"}
```

code:

```
public class AddBatchObject {

    private String[] deviceAddr;

    public String[] getDeviceAddr() {
        return deviceAddr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String batch = "";
        if (deviceAddr != null){
           batch += "deviceAaddr - " + "size = " + deviceAddr.length + ", "  
           + Arrays.asList(deviceAddr).toString() + "\n";
        }
        if (devicePass != null){
           batch += "devicePass - " + "size = " + devicePass.length + ", " +
               Arrays.asList(devicePass).toString() + "\n";
        }
        return batch;
    }

}
```

rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/mac",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =     "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Object addMac(@RequestBody AddBatchObject addBatchObject, HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException{
    LoggerUtils.getLogger().info("addMac");
    return AdminAddMac.adminAddMac(addBatchObject,request);
}
```

> Edit:      as jtahlborn and Joe answered the json data was
>   incorrect: ["0022C01504D3,0022C015050F"] is a single element array. a
>   two element array would be ["0022C01504D3","0022C015050F"].

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of the behaviour.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: try this `batch += "'" + deviceAddr[0] + "'";`

Comment: Also `Arrays.toString(deviceAddr);` is slightly clearer than going through `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: your json data is incorrect: `["0022C01504D3,0022C015050F"]` is a single element array.  a two element array would be `["0022C01504D3","0022C015050F"]`.

Comment: @jtahlborn that realy was the issue, I wasn't responsible for the json request, it was odd to me since my code did went through the first iteration succesfully. anyway im not his fan but god bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct.  Your JSON contains one string that has a comma in it, rather than two distinct strings.

The JSON you probably want is:

```
{"deviceAddr":["0022C01504D3","0022C015050F"],"devicePass":["HOMI26","HOMI26"],"deviceCount":2,"version":"MU18"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json string is proper json with 4 key-value pairs. You can put it in a file `data.txt`

```
{
    "deviceAddr": ["0022C01504D3,0022C015050F"],
    "devicePass": ["HOMI26,HOMI26"],
    "deviceCount": 2,
    "version": "MU18"
}
```

and read it with `jackson`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(new File("data.txt"));
        jp.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
        JsonNode jsonNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
        readJsonData(jsonNode);
    }
    static void readJsonData(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> ite = jsonNode.fields();
        while(ite.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = ite.next();
            if(entry.getValue().isObject()) {
                readJsonData(entry.getValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println("key:"+entry.getKey()+", value:"+entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
key:deviceAddr, value:["0022C01504D3,0022C015050F"]
key:devicePass, value:["HOMI26,HOMI26"]
key:deviceCount, value:2
key:version, value:"MU18"
```

I hope this will help you.